# Subsetting a list of different data types

Tags: r

I have a list of different data types (factors, data.frames, and vectors, all the same length or number of rows), What I would like to do is subset each element of the list by a vector (let's call it rows) that represents row names.

If it was a data.frame() I would:

```
x <- x[rows,]
```

If it was a vector() or factor() I would:

```
x <- x[rows]
```

So, I've been playing around with this:

```
x <- lapply(my_list, function(x) ifelse(is.data.frame(x), x[rows,], x[rows]))
```

So, how do I accomplish my goal of getting a list of subsetted data?

Comment: Do you have sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is YAIEP (Yet Another If Else Problem). From `?ifelse`:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

See the trouble? Same shape as test.

So just do this:

```
l <- list(a = data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),b = 1:10, c = factor(letters[1:20]))

rows <- 1:3

fun <- function(x){
    if (is.data.frame(x)){
        x[rows,]
    }
    else{
        x[rows]
    }
}

lapply(l,fun)
```

Comment: /me slaps forehead. Thanks J.